# Selecting audio file from device, ionic framework cordova

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i need to pick an audio file from my device so i could save the path in my sqlite db even playback this audio file in a future user request.

i am using cordova media file for record and playback the audio but i need to have the option to pick the audio file from device too. there is a plugin for this?, i will appreciate your help, regards.

my template look like this, first div for play audio, second div for record audio and finally third div for select audio from device:

```html
<div class="col col-offset-20">
                
                <a ng-click="playing(editsimpleRow.custom_sound_path,'/android_asset/www/raw/'+editsimpleRow.sound_title+'.mp3',editsimpleValue.custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                    <!--<a ng-click="play(editsimple.custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>-->
            
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a on-hold="recordStart(editsimpleRow.sound_title)" on-release="recordEnd()"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/mic.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>   
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a ng-click=" "><img ng-src="img/sonidos/gallery.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
            </div>
```